# How to make a non-greedy regex for following?

Tags: regex

I have something like this:
...

```
<div class="viewport viewport_h" style = "overflow: hidden;" >
    <div id="THIS" class="overview overview_h">
        <ul>
                 <li>some txt to be captured</li>
                 <li>some txt to be captured</li>
                 <li>some txt to be captured</li>
        </ul>
        <div>
            " some text to be captured"
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
"some text not to be captured"
</div>
<div class="scrollbar_h">
<div class="track_h"></div>
```

...

I want to capture everything inside `div` with `id=THIS`. I'm using somthing like:

```
@<div class="viewport viewport_h" style = "overflow: hidden;" >\s*<div class="overview overview_h">\s*(?:<ul>)?([\s\d\w<>\/()="-:;‘’!,:]+)(?:</div>)+?@
```

The last `(?:</div>)+?` is to make it non-greedy for further "</div>" but that doesn't work and captuers all other following `</div>`. :(

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: I don't think a regex is the right answer to it. You should try to look at some XML parser since XML is a context free language (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar).

Maybe this post can help you : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: Is it PHP or JavaScript? Use DOM/XPATH to get some specific tags, that will be most precise, readable  and maintainable.

Comment: It is PHP and I want to go regex way only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments `regex` is not a proper way for parsing `(?:X|H)TML` documents.

Let consider your example one straight way for that is following regex :

```
<div[^>]*id="THIS"[^>]*>(.*?)</div>
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yQ1pO1/1)

That will match following text :

```
    <ul>
             <li>some txt to be captured</li>
             <li>some txt to be captured</li>
             <li>some txt to be captured</li>
    </ul>
    <div>
        " some text to be captured"
    </div>
```

As you can see its not the proper result as you need another `</div>` so you need to count the open `div`s to be able to detect the closing `div`s
 that its all based on the language you are using.

Now in this case if you want to create a none-greedy ending dive you need to put a `dot` before `+` like following :

```
<div[^>]*id="THIS"[^>]*>(.*?)(</div>).+?
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yQ1pO1/2)

Now it will match another `</div>` but still its hard for regex to detect the true result (its more complicated for another situation).and it's the reason that the proper way for parsing `(?:X|H)TML` is using a `(?:X|H)TML Parser`